Trouble connecting to the northbound kafka interface from a remote machine with hono-cli
I'm setting up hono on a server, to which I look to connect from my local machine. However, I cannot get hono-cli to connect when running on my local machine.
Hono setup:

Using minikube, with docker as driver and minikube tunnel
Using the default helm chart, installed according to the documentation https://github.com/eclipse/packages/blob/master/charts/hono/README.md
I port forwarded the ports for the amqp, http, mqtt, kafka controller and device registry services (5671, 8443, 8883, 9094, 28443) using kubectl port-forward, e.g. nohup kubectl port-forward service/eclipse-hono-adapter-amqp 5671:5671 -n hono &

Remote connection:

ssh tunnel of the previously mentioned ports, such that I can access them locally ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 -L 5671:localhost:5671 -L 8443:localhost:8443 -L 8883:localhost:8883 -L 9094:localhost:9094 -L 28443:localhost:28443 mylogin@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Observed problem:
I can run hono-cli on the hono server without problems, publishing data with HTTP or MQTT works both from the server itself, or from a new terminal on my local machine.
Running hono-cli locally on my machine, it gets stuck at Connecting to Kafka based messaging infrastructure [localhost:9094]
The complete command is (the same for the server, as for the locally): java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar app -H localhost -P 9094 -u hono -p hono-secret --ca-file ~/hono-cafile/truststore.pem --disable-hostname-verification consume --tenant tenant-name
EDIT Workaround:
As a workaround I've set up hono again but with the AMQP northbound interface rather than kafka. This works as expected, so I'm continuing with this setup. Nonetheless, I think the question can remain open in case others really need the kafka interface.
Alternatively, you might try running minikube with option --driver=none, but for me this caused other problems, since I'm on Debian, which no longer uses iptables.
Question
How would I go about troubleshooting this further? Does hono-cli require other ports to be forwarded as well?
